# Masonry and the masonry-brick class

Tags: javascript, web, jquery-masonry

I'm new to web programming and not entirely sure what my Masonry code is doing... Each element that I have in the container I'm applying Masonry to is being moved around (like one would expect) however the masonry-brick class isn't being applied to the child elements within the container. See below:

My JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {

  var colWid = Math.floor($('#article_display').width() *.25);
  console.log(colWid);
  var $article_display = $('#article_display');
  $('#article_display').imagesLoaded(function() {
    $article_display.masonry({
      columnWidth: colWid,
      itemSelector: '.article',
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
    });
  });
});
```

Sample child element (note the positioning, that seems to be applied via Masonry):

```
<div class="article featured" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 378px;"><img       src="http://placehold.it/292x468"></div>
```

This is the container I'm  referencing (again you can see some style changes by it doesn't have the "masonry" class that I expect it to):

```
<div id="article_display" class="span12" style="position: relative; height: 943px;">
```

Here is a related article, I basically do what this guy does but am not seeing the same results he is, I think that there has been a new release since he published his question  so the solution has changed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972117/masonry-not-working-class-of-masonry-brick-is-not-being-applied.

Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I'm really asking if the "masonry-brick" and "masonry" classes are supposed to be applied to elements that are affected by the Masonry plugin, just in case the question wasn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Desandro "Masonry v3 no longer adds these classes to the elements." Closing this out.